# Securely routing all traffic in a home network through a secondary firewall/gateway

Tags: networking, wireless-router, firewall, adsl-router

FYI, I'm not a networking expert by way a long shot :-). I Have a plain simple home networking setup: a VDSL modem/router with home devices directly connecting to it mostly through wireless. I'd like to introduce a gateway/firewall device (without wireless) into the network (wired to the VDSL modem/router), while:

1. keeping all the end devices connecting through the VDSL wireless (speculative design below)
2. routing all traffic through the firewall/gateway

Is that even conceivably feasible ?

```
                             +-------+
              +------>-------|gateway|
              |              +---+---+
[VDSL modem]--+                  |
  ^   ^--------------<-----------+
  |
  |         wireless
  +------+----------+--------+
         |          |        |
        Tablet   Laptop1   Laptop2
```

Comment: To what degree can you configure your VDSL router? With vendor provided firmware, that's probably not feasible. With something like OpenWRT on it, it is (but not obvious to set up), but then you could run the firefall on the VDSL router in the first place.

Comment: @dirkt The  router is a SmartRG SR515AC. As far as I could find, it's not amenable to flashing.

Comment: Does your DSL connection use PPPoE, or PPPoA, or just plain DHCP/IPoE?

Comment: @user1686 PPPoE